# Does there always exist an open set in bigger space that lying over a given open set in smaller space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric or topological space. $Y\subseteq X$ be its subspace. Let $V\subseteq Y$ be open with respect to the smaller subspace $Y$ (i.e. $V$ may be not open with respect to $X$). Then I wonder is there always an open set $U$ with respect to $X$, such that $U\cap Y=V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. For each $x\in V$, there is some $r_x>0$ such that $D(x,r_x)\cap Y\subset V$, by definition of open set in a metric space. So, take $U=\bigcup_{x\in V}D(x,r_x)$, and that will be an open subset of $X$ such that $U\cap Y=V$.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the definition of the subspace topology. A subset in the subspace is open if and only if it is the intersection of an open subset in the larger space with the subspace.

Comment: Oh I see! However, if we're talking about only metric spaces (pretending we haven't learnt topological space), the simplest way to show the fact (in metric space) is by @José Carlos Santos's method right?

Comment: @Eric I was under the impression from the wording that the metric space condition is not required. If it is then Jose's method works well.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer remind me there is a more direct (definition!) way to argue it in topological space. And Jose's answer helps me on metric space case. Thank both of you. (Jose was first to answer, so I accept him.)

Comment: @Eric Sure, no problem.